# Transfer data from one page to another in Next 13 server components without showing it in query params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a use case for passing data from one page to another in Next 13. I know we can use the query option in `Link` to pass data but the data that is passed shows up in query params in the URL. It is not a big deal until the data object you are passing is huge. Also other options are to use state which is client side which is not possible in my case. So is there a walkaround this? here is my demo code:

page from data need to be sent:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: "/posts/abc",
        query: {
          data: "hello",
        },
      }}
    >
      Click Me
    </Link>
  );
}
```

page where data need to be received

```
export default function page({ searchParams }) {
  console.log(searchParams.data);
  return <div>hello</div>;
}
```